# GDB can't insert internal breakpoint

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, shared-libraries, proc

I added two breakpoints in functions of one shared library (.so) and ran `gdb 7.4` and attached it to a process.

Gdb hit the breakpoint and I ran `n` for several steps, and gdb reported the following errors(with **bold** text):

> (gdb) b [function name]
>   Breakpoint 1 at 0xf1f28a49: file ../../../../../[file name].cpp, line 167.
>   Breakpoint 2 at 0xf1f2dae5: file ../../../../../[file name].cpp, line 60.
>   warning: Multiple breakpoints were set.
>   Use the "delete" command to delete unwanted breakpoints.
>   (gdb) c
>   Continuing.
>   [New Thread 0xcaafab90 (LWP 28480)]
>   [Thread 0xcaafab90 (LWP 28480) exited]
>   [New Thread 0xcaafab90 (LWP 29558)]
>   [New Thread 0xc8cb6b90 (LWP 29980)]
>   [Switching to Thread 0xc8cb6b90 (LWP 29980)]
>   
>   Breakpoint 2, [function name] (ostr=..., clientResponse=..., httpProtocol=..., >reqType=...) at ../../../../../[file name].cpp:60
>   60      ../../../../../[file name].cpp: No such file or directory.
>          in ../../../../../[file name].cpp
>   (gdb) ni
>   0xf1f2daed      60      in ../../../../../[file name].cpp
>   (gdb) n
>   
>   Breakpoint 1, [function name] (ostr=..., clientResponse=..., httpProtocol=..., >closeConn=..., asynchResponse=..., reqType=...)
>      at ../../../../../[file name].cpp:167
>   167     in ../../../../../[file name].cpp
>   (gdb) n
>   Warning:
>   **Cannot insert breakpoint 0.**
>   **Error accessing memory address 0x36cc6dde: Input/output error.**
>   
>   0xf7082771 in siglongjmp () from /lib/libc.so.6
>   (gdb)

This is the output from `/proc/[PID]/maps`:

> 08048000-08146000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 293876
>   
>  08146000-08150000 rw-p 000fe000 08:03 293876
>   
>  08150000-099c8000 rw-p 08150000 00:00 0
>   [heap]
>  c21f9000-c21fa000 ---p c21f9000 00:00 0
>   c21fa000-c29fa000 rwxp c21fa000 00:00 0
>  c29fa000-c29fb000 ---p
>   c29fa000 00:00 0
>  ……
>  f1e1b000-f1e24000 rw-p f1e1b000 00:00
>   0
>  f1e24000-f2093000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 295549
>   .so
>  f2093000-f2094000 ---p 0026f000 08:03 295549
>   .so
>  f2094000-f2098000 r--p 0026f000 08:03 295549
>   .so
>  f2098000-f209c000 rw-p 00273000 08:03 295549
>   .so
>  f209c000-f209d000 rw-p f209c000 00:00 0

My questions are:

1. Gdb fails to insert internal breakpoint for `ni` command, but why does it try to access address `0x36cc6dde` if the text section is at `0xf1******`?That address is not included in the output of maps as you can see.
2. More general question, I was told shared library starts at `0x40000000` but why this is not the case in my environment?

The shared library is compiled with `-fPIC`. I hide some symbol names in the traces above.

Comment: Mmm addresess above 0xc0000000 usually are address in which kernel is mapped. Why is your process using thiese addresses in userspace?

Answer (score -2):

This is probably related to http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13987.  Please, could you try the latest FSF GDB HEAD (can be obtained from: git://sourceware.org/git/gdb.git).